# Locked Balance of an Account in Acala

Tags: balances, acala

Is it possible to retrieve the locked balance of an account from the account data queried from `api.query.system.account`? If not, what is the right way to do so? I'm looking for the stash locked in bonds, democracy, election and vesting.

Answer (score 1):

The locked values are stored in [balances.locks](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#locksaccountid32-vecpalletbalancesbalancelock) and the vesting information in [vesting.vesting](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#vestingaccountid32-optionvecpalletvestingvestinginfo).

The locks has identifiers that point to the specific pallets that performed the locks.